# Apache mod_proxy and Caching

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, mod-proxy

We have apache servers that proxy content from an application server and also from a legacy web server. We enabled caching using our load balancer, but the caching is not behaving like we expect it to. Here is our setup:

We're setting cache headers specifically for the pages served from our application server using:

```
<Location ~ /(appDir1|appDir2|appDir3)>
Header set Cache-Control max-age=3600,public
</Location>
```

This works fine.

On the legacy server, the sys admin has set this in his Apache virtual host that runs his legacy site:

```
Header set Cache-Control max-age=0,private,no-cache
```

However, our load balancers are still caching the legacy content that we proxy.

When we visit http://appHost/legacyDir1 - we see cached content. When we visit http://legacyHost/legacyDir1 - we see the non-cached content. At least in theory, we're expecting to see non-cached at http://appHost/legacyDir1.

Any ideas what we might be missing ... ?

KM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the load balancer settings. The LB had to be configured to match the various pages that needed to be cached.